# android listview get selected item

Tags: android, listview, onclick, selecteditem

I am new to android, I have a code in which I have placed buttons in list view.
My list is as..

```
Number | Name | ID (visibility = gone) | Level | button1 | button2
```

Function is different in button 1 and button 2 case. I have applied listeners on buttons but when I try to get the ID from list it always shows me the last id.

How to know which button was clicked, name and id of related field.

I have placed buttons and listener on buttons in `getView(...)` function.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

      }                 
});
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I have a button in my listView and action listener is attached on the button. I know that on which button action was performed but how to get the id on which it was clicked ??? please look at question again.

Comment: I don't want to put action listener on list, rather on child of listView button.

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        Button btnFetchId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
      }                 
}

Comment: hey I got it... I simply user btn.setTag() and set the value I want to receive and where I want i simply did btn.getTag() ..

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13891 . any workaround ? i think, on every textchange, i'll do a backup of my data, and in onSelect() , i'll get the value in my backup

Comment: got this error in logcat: java.lang.ClassCastException:  cannot be cast to java.lang.String