# how to assign the selected item from list view to a variable

Tags: java, android

On item selection I am able to show the value of a column through toast. Now I 
want that value to get assigned to a variable. I tried with the commented line 
but get some junk information like:

```
android.widget.TextView{41f04c60 V.ED..}.
```

**CODE:**

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                          View view, int position, long thislist) {
        TextView selectedTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedTitle.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //selectedTitleID = String.valueOf((TextView) 
                                              view.findViewById(R.id.textView));

        }
```

Comment: But getting value using `selectedTitle.getText()` then what is issue?

Comment: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 TextView selectedTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
 String selectedTitleID  = selectedTitle.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selected item will be:

```
Object selectedItem = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Now You can cast this item to any class and get `selectedTitleId`;

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get from adapter.You need to mention like this.

```
   @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
    String title= (String) ((TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textView)).getText(); //from adapter
    Toast.makeText(this,"Title is"+ title , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing in your itemclick

```
String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

You can also find your answer in :

[android listview get selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508979/android-listview-get-selected-item)