# Delete a specific item from list in firebase with onClick

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have tried reading the documentation on it and I understand that I need to use removeValue() to accomplish this, I just don't know how to get the position of the click. I am pulling the list down from firebase and trying to use an OnItemClick() to say anytime something in the listview is clicked, it will be deleted. I feel like this is super simple and I'm just missing something.

```
public class DeleteChoiceListFragment extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mRestReference = mRootRef.child("restaurants");

List<String> listofrest = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView restaurantListView;
ListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;





public DeleteChoiceListFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_selection_list_frag,container,false);
    restaurantListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);

    restaurantListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Restaurants>(getActivity(),Restaurants.class,R.layout.individual_restaurant_name_nocheckbox,mRestReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Restaurants model, final int position) {
            TextView restName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restname);
            restName.setText(model.getName());

            listofrest.add(position,model.getName());
        }
    };

    restaurantListView.setAdapter(restaurantListAdapter);
    restaurantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        }
    });
    return view;

}

}
```

Going on 36 hours of no sleep now so my brain is 100% dead. I can provide more detail if necessary

Comment: onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)   here , i is your position

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34029120/2949612

Answer (score 0):

Implement your setOnItemClickListener like this

```
restaurantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Firebase itemtoRemove = restaurantListAdapter.getRef(i);
    itemtoRemove.removeValue();

    }
});
```

add your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
```

Comment: add your gradle file compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'

Comment: ok I have Firebase now but I get an error trying to call getRef. says it can't be. Everything else seems fine. and I added those to my gradle

Comment: specific error is Error:(70, 53) error: cannot find symbol method getRef(int)

Comment: refer https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html

Comment: @sasikumar please don't mix Firebase versions. If you want to use 9.8.0, use that version of all Firebase libraries.