# How can I set the onItemClick method to show the Text that I clicked in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

just start my learning in Android. This is a small question but I really want to know how to solve it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView l;
    String [] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView, days);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the data in `days` array. `position` argument of `onItemClick` method points to which item position you clicked in the `ListView`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selected = days[position];
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, what if I also want to get the index of the text I just clicked? I tried to change `days[position]` to `days[id]` but it is not working.

Comment: The `position` itself is the index.

Comment: Hi, what should I do to make the text and the index of that text to show up in the Toast message? Thank you!

Comment: `postion + " " + selected`

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectedFromList =(String) (l.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/4509011/5766770)

Edit: Neeraj's code is probably the better solution