# get data of listview item on click

Tags: android, json, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

hey guys i am new to xamarin android , i created a listview which takes value of json format i want to get the name or the id of the listview clicked item and i don't know how..

here is my class

```
  class Doctors
    {
        public int id;

        public string Name;
        public string address;
        public string spec;
        public string rating;
        public string fee;


        public Doctors(string Name, string address, string spec, string rating, string fee)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.address = address;
            this.spec = spec;
            this.rating = rating;
            this.fee = fee;
        }

    }
```

and here is my adapter

```
 class DoctorsAdapter : BaseAdapter<Doctors>
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private int mRowLayout;
        private List<Doctors> mFriends;


        public DoctorsAdapter(Context context, int rowLayout, List<Doctors> friends)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mRowLayout = rowLayout;
            mFriends = friends;

        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return mFriends.Count; }
        }

        public override Doctors this[int position]
        {
            get { return mFriends[position]; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mRowLayout, parent, false);
            }




            TextView name = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.docname);
            name.Text = mFriends[position].Name;



            TextView spec = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.docspec);
            spec.Text = mFriends[position].spec;

            TextView address = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.docadd);
            address.Text = mFriends[position].address;

            TextView feeetv = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.feetv);
            feeetv.Text = mFriends[position].fee;

            RatingBar doctorrating = row.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.docrating);
            doctorrating.Rating = Int32.Parse(mFriends[position].rating);

            return row;
        }


    }
```

and this the method which populates listview with json

```
  private void populatelistview()
    {
        if (jsonString == null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "json is null", ToastLength.Long);

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //  jsonobject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
                jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
                mDoctors = new List<Doctors>();
                int count = 0;
                while (count < jsonArray.Count)
                {
                    Doctors doctor = new Doctors(jsonArray[count]["Name"].ToString(), jsonArray[count]["spec"].ToString(), jsonArray[count]["address"].ToString(), jsonArray[count]["rating"].ToString(), jsonArray[count]["fees"].ToString());
                    //      Toast.MakeText(this, jsonArray[count]["name"].ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    mDoctors.Add(doctor);
                    count++;
                }

                mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.docview);
                mAdapter = new DoctorsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ticket_result, mDoctors);
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
                mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
            }
            catch (System.Exception exception)
            {

                Toast.MakeText(this, exception.ToString(), ToastLength.Long);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android listview get selected item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508979/android-listview-get-selected-item)

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get the name or the id of the listview clicked item

You can implement your `MListView_ItemClick` like this:

```
private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.Position;
    var item = mDoctors[position] as Doctors;
    var name = item.Name;
    var id = item.id;
}
```

First get the position where the item is clicked, then find the matched item in your `mDoctors`, and finally you can get the `Name` and `id` you defined in this item.